# Spider web chart in JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How to create the Spider Web Chart using JQuery?
Is there any one can help me to create the Spider Web Chart using JQuery in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jumware's [Plugins](http://jumware.com/Includes/jquery/Flot/Examples/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need for a JavaScript spider chart. The Jumware plugin to flot (as mentioned by Doozer1979 above) sort of works, but the labels are messed up. If you look at the flot plugin page, another user suggests a fix, but the fix breaks the highlighting. The author suggested they were working on a new version, but so far nothing new has materialized.

I ended up using the charting library from the dojo toolkit. It works, but I'm not entirely happy with how heavy-weight the dojo toolkit is and how slow it runs.

I'm still looking for jquery charting library with support for spider plots.

**Update**: It looks like the Jumware spider plot plugin has been updated now, but it's still not as attractive as the Dojo one.